# I have a string (i.e. char* str), and when I compare it against the empty string (i.e. *str != "\0") I get an error.What's wrong?

Tags: c, string

I am trying to find the length of a string. I defined the function

```
int stringLength(char* str){
    char* strPointer = str;
    int length = 0;

    while((*strPointer) != "\0"){
        length++;
        strPointer++;
    }

    return length;
}
```

I get a warning:

```
warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]                                                                                               
 while((*strPointer) != "\0")
```

I cannot see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: try changing "\0" to '\0' ,,, and why don't you just use strlen?

Comment: `char *` is a pointer, not a string!

Comment: and dereferencing a `char *` gives you what? (hint: a `char`) which you attempt to compare against an empty *string literal*.

Answer (score 4):

`*strPointer` is de-referencing an array of character so it is a character.
So the comparison has to be made against  a character.
You need to replace double quote to a single quote like this:

```
 while((*strPointer) != '\0'){
```